# Inductor dc resistance simulations

Tags: resistance, inductor, simulation

How can I simulate the dc resistance/R_dc of a spiral inductor?
Here's the circuit I have:

[image]

I simulate the inductor with a dc source and get the series current from a I_probe.
Then calculated the dc resistance with R_dc=Vdc/I. Am I doing the right thing here?

(P.S. I didn't run a s-parameter sweep here because it gives me effective resistance = R_ac+R_dc, right?)

Edited: I am simulating with ADS.

Comment: You might add the simulator software name and hyperlink into your question. It will probably affect the answer.

Comment: Where is Vds in your schematic? Do you understand the notion of complex impedance and inductive reactance?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Sorry for the typo. I mean Vdc. I used DC source in simulation. Since it's purely in dc, it would not have R+Xj notion, right?

Comment: Yes, at dc there is no reactance...so what do you mean by R_ac?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Oh, my last sentence probably confuses you. I am looking for R_dc. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

> Then calculated the dc resistance with R_dc=Vdc/I

Yes, this is correct.

It might be marginally better to simulate with a current source, so the simulation doesn't blow up in case the inductor model has 0 dc resistance.

And of course this tells you what the resistance is in the simulation model. It doesn't necessarily tell you what the resistance of a real device would be, unless you've actually input good values for the simulator to calculate from.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am wondering how could I calculate the dc resistance of a spiral inductor? If I do a EM simulation, would it be more accurate?

Comment: @Missfresstyle, no simulation is any more accurate than the model you provide it. Do you know the actual material composition of the structure you're modeling? The metal thickness? The surface roughness? Etc.

Comment: Yes, I do have an approximated substrate to run simulation. The problem I am seeing is that the EM-simulated inductor has much less R_dc compared to the schematic model. I am not sure which one to trust.

Comment: The metal geometry will be much more important to finding R than the substrate.

Comment: How about if I am using a developed design kit which has its metal layouts ready for simulation?